# Правильно ли поставлены знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Среди них есть и старые, уже общеизвестные (вроде сайентологов и "Свидетелей Иеговы"), и новые, только-только зародившиеся, религиозные движения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно оставить предложенный вариант с обособлением (он мне кажется более подходящим), а можно представить определения как однородные:

Среди них есть и старые, уже общеизвестные (вроде сайентологов и "Свидетелей Иеговы") и новые, только-только зародившиеся религиозные движения.

Comment: Мне показался более естественным вариант без запятой (видимо, потому, что в этом месте нет речевой паузы). Попытался сопоставить своё впечатление с существующими рекомендациями, но пока нашёл только такой источник (http://www.licey.net/russian/syntax/r1_2_8):

1) Обособление уточняющих согласованных определений – явление достаточно редкое и во многом зависит от воли пишущего. Обычно определения с уточняющим значением рассматриваются как однородные, то есть запятая ставится не с двух сторон, а с одной – между определениями.

Answer (score 2):

Последняя запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая действительно не нужна. Препозитивное определение, выраженное причастием,  стоящее непосредственно перед определяемым существительным, обособляется, если помимо атрибутивного имеет также обстоятельственное значение (причинное, условное, уступительное). В вашем примере нет такого оттенка.

Comment: Серж, здесь при обособлении значение уточнения/пояснения: старые, то есть общеизвестные, и новые, то есть только-только зародившиеся. Вот и делается выбор, как представить определения (уточняющие или однородные).

Comment:  Писатели-классики иногда выделяли запятыми в качестве уточняющего определения причастный оборот, стоящий поcле однородного определения-прилагательного. Например, у И. С. Тургенева: Он устроил большую, полотном покрытую, купальню; В ста шагах от мельницы находился маленький, со всех сторон открытый, навес; Из особенной, мною сперва не замеченной, конюшни вывели Павлина. **В настоящее время такая пунктуация встречается редко**. Д.Э. Розенталь.

Comment: Уточняющими могут быть определения (обычно уточнения касаются размера, цвета, возраста) и приложения.  Поэтому запятую лучше не **СТАВИТЬ!**

Comment: Если не уточнение, то явное пояснение, раскрытие содержания понятий "новые и старые".

Comment: Определения, носящие характер пояснения (перед ними можно поставить слова а именно, то есть и т. п.), отделяются запятой от поясняемого слова, но после них запятая не ставится: Торчали толстые головни, остатки прежней, сгоревшей бани (М. Г.); В романе показаны старые, исчезающие и новые, **зарождающиеся явления** общественной жизни.

Comment: Вопрос об отделении с одной стороны или выделении с двух сторон пояснительного определения решается в условиях контекста. Ср.:

Четвёртая, последняя часть романа завершится эпилогом. — Четвёртая, по-видимому последняя, часть романа завершится эпилогом;[О вводных словах в составе обособленного оборота см. § 25, п. 4.](http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_25.htm#ppp_4)

Comment: Другой, не менее важный раздел соглашения посвящен вопросам культурного сотрудничества. — Другой, и не менее важный, раздел соглашения посвящен вопросам культурного сотрудничества — определение носит присоединительный характер благодаря наличию присоединительного союза и[см. § 24].(http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_24.htm)

Comment: При одинаковой пунк-и в некоторых случаях сближаются различные по типу опред-я. Например: Рядом с этими домами высятся другие здания — жилые, административные, торговые — возможные толкования: а) од/o-я после обобщающего слово-я другие здания [см. § 15, п. 5]( [см. § 15, п. 5];); б) обособ/o-я в конце предложения [см. § 18, п. 1](http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_18.htm#ppp_1) в) поясн-е опр-я (…другие, а именно…) [см. § 10, п. 10](http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_10.htm#ppp_10); г)

Comment: г) присоединительные определения (бессоюзное присоединение)(http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_24.htm#ppp_6) [см. § 24, п. 6].

Comment: Не вижу причин для того, чтобы не обособить следующие определения, а главное, не вижу причин для жесткой регламентации и отсутствия права на авторское решение: Он приобрел старую, датированную концом XVIII века, картину. Дашу удивила доморощенность всего этого, так нашумевшего, дерзновения. Пьер, с раннего утра стянутый в неловком, сделавшемся ему узким,  мундире, был уже в залах.

Answer (score 0):

Уважаемая Майя!
Если это возможно, вышлите, пожалуйста, мне Ваш контактный телефон,
чтобы я смогла с Вами переговорить насчёт методики лечения.
Как я Вам уже сказала, мы специализируемся как раз на таком маленьком возрасте.
У нас проходил лечение пациент Воробьёв Георгий.
Малышу было 13 месяцев, с тяжелейшими генетическими отклонениями, с нарушением темпов двигательного аппарата и также с нарушением речи.
Наши реабилитологи в кратчайший срок добились результатов. Вы не представляете, всего за месяц он пошёл на поправку.
Он не мог сидеть самостоятельно, не мог выговаривать звуки.
Благодаря работе физиотерапевтов малыш пошёл на поправку.

Answer (score -1):

Последняя зпт. факультативна. Постановка или нет определяется автором для указания на фразовое  ударение.

Comment: Интонационная структура (фразовые ударения, паузы и т.д.) выражают определенную семантику, поэтому недостаточно указать на изменение фразового ударения, надо пояснить, как это влияет на смысл сообщения.